# Как получить значение свойства "bottom" (JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой html:

```
 <div class="correspondence">
            <section class="temp-login-user-message">
                <img src="img/unknown_male.png" alt="user-photo" id="user-photo">
                <p id="user-message">Some text</p>
                <p id="message-status">✓✓</p>
            </section>
 </div>
```

И css для этого блока html:

```
.correspondence{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #346ABC;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.temp-login-user-message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

И в js я пытаюсь получить значение свойства "bottom" класса "temp-login-user-message":

```
var messageBlock = document.getElementById("temp-login-user-message");
var bottomProp = messageBlock.style.bottom;
console.log(bottomProp);
```

Однако в консоль выводит пустую строку, вместо "200px". В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В консоль выводит не пустую строку, а ошибку.

Comment: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".temp-login-user-message");
var bottomProp = getComputedStyle(element).bottom;
console.log(bottomProp);
```

```css
.correspondence {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  border-top: none;
  background-color: #346ABC;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.temp-login-user-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="correspondence">
  <section class="temp-login-user-message">
    <img src="img/unknown_male.png" alt="user-photo" id="user-photo">
    <p id="user-message">Some text</p>
    <p id="message-status">✓✓</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Теперь вместо пустой строки выдаёт auto.

Comment: @SyXa4 Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том, что у вас нет элемента с `id` `temp-login-user-message`. Просто добавьте элементу `section` id со значением `temp-login-user-message` в html, а для получения значения свойства `bottom`, используйте метод `getComputedStyle`.

Можете ознакомиться с методом `getComputedStyle` [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes#vychislennye-stili-getcomputedstyle).

```js
var messageBlock = document.getElementById("temp-login-user-message");
var bottomProp = getComputedStyle(messageBlock).bottom;
alert(bottomProp);
```

```css
correspondence{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #346ABC;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.temp-login-user-message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="correspondence">
            <section id="temp-login-user-message" class="temp-login-user-message">
                <img src="img/unknown_male.png" alt="user-photo" id="user-photo">
                <p id="user-message">Some text</p>
                <p id="message-status">✓✓</p>
            </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: Теперь вместо пустой строки выдаёт auto.

Comment: Если вы здесь проверите это, то должны увидеть 200px, попробуйте посмотреть на этом сайте, нажав Выполнить код @SyXa4